# Is $f$ can take the value $w$ at finitely many points ?Yes/No

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the  following statement  true/false  ?

> let  $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$  be  an analytic  function.For  $w \in \mathbb{C}$  . Then $f$    can take  the  value  $w$  at  finitely  many points  in  $\{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

**My attempt** : I think this  statement is false  take  $f(1/n)  = w + \frac{1}{n}$

I think this  statement is true  for  when $n \to \infty$

$\implies$  true for infinitely  many points  in  $\{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Also , we  can used identity theorem  take $g(z_n)= f(z_n) -w$

then $g(z_n) =0$  for  all $n \in \mathbb{N}$   since  $z_n \to 0$  as $\frac{1}{n}  \to 0$  as $ n \to \infty$

**My  thinking** :$f$    can take  the  value  $w$  at  infinitely  many points  in  $\{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

But  not possible at  finitely  many points  in  $\{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Comment: I don't understand the "attempt". If $f(z)=w+z$, then $f$ takes on the value $w$ only at one point, $z=0$. It doesn't take on the value $w$ at any $z=1/n$, only at $z=0$. But it's not clear to me what exactly you are trying to prove.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sir  Actually, I am trying to show that the $n$ is not finite .It  is true  for  $n \to \infty$

Comment: Are you sure that the problem statement is cited correctly? I would expect something like "*let  $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$  be  an analytic  function **which is not constant**. -For- **Let**  $w \in \mathbb{C}$  . Then $f$    can take  the  value  $w$  at  **at most** finitely  many points  in  $\{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.*" Emphasis mine.

Comment: @StinkingBishop My question is cited correctly

Comment: Okay, but isn't it trivial then? Take $f(z)=(z-1/n_1)(z-1/n_2)\cdots(z-1/n_k)+w$ and $f(z)=w$ for $z\in\{1/n_1,1/n_2,\ldots,1/n_k\}$ which is a finite subset of $\{1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z)=z-1$ and $w=0$ then the only solution of $f(\frac 1 n) =w$ occurs when $n=1$.

However, the following holds: If $\{z: f(z)=w\} \subseteq \{1,\frac 1 2, \frac 1  3,\cdots\}$ then  $\{z: f(z)=w\}$ is finite (or empty).